# How to format datetime using react-moment library

Tags: reactjs

I want to format date and time by having string value. Therefore, I want my property to hold a formatted date and time using a library react-moment and return the local time. All this must be a function which I'll callback in my table. How could I make this?

```
import * as React from 'react';

type Props = {
    value: string;
};

const DateTimeColumn = (props: Props) => {
    const { value } = props;
    // TODO:
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, it is not very clear what are you asking. My guess is that you have a date-time string in UTC-0 and you want a component that will receive that date-time  string and will display it in the user's timezone.

Comment: ```return value ? moment(value).format('LLL') : null;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply return the converted date like so:

```
import Moment from 'react-moment';

const DateTimeColumn = (props: Props) => {
    const { value } = props;
    return (
       <Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD" date={value} />
    )
}
```